# Responsiveness of image element in web page building

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When I was working on website building , I could not bring an image element  perfectly  to my desired shape(circle) in all responsive breakpoints i.e if i tried to make it good in small screens then it got disturbed for large screens and vice versa.
What should I probably do ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Well i'm not quite sure i understand your question, but have you tried media queries?
You can simply specify elements position and size for different screen sizes, here's some reference: [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

For giving the picture a circular shape you can use border-radius: 50%;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).